# rewrite to Danish time / date

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Hello this is how I am building my own forum but this is how I must have "set" date into the database that is such 30-5-2012 should look but how it should also look out when pulls it out of the database. I build it up like this in MySQLI

Here's how it looks when I located it in the database

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="formular" onsubmit="return validerform ()">
            <?php
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `forum` (`title`, `tekst`, `dato`, `id_brugere`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)')) { 
            $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $title, $tekst, $dato, $id_brugere);
            //fra input ting ting..
            $title = $_POST["title"];
            $tekst = $_POST["tekst"];
            $id_brugere = $_SESSION["user_id"];
            $dato = date('d-m-Y');

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

            //er der fejl i tilgangen til table..
            } else {
                echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklÃ¦ringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
            }
            ?>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td id="tb-w_a"><p>Title</p></td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="title"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <textarea name="tekst" style="width:716px; height:170px;"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Opret indhold">
</form>
```

Here's how it looks when I take it out of the database

```
<?php
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id_forum, title, tekst, dato, id_brugere FROM `forum` ORDER BY  `forum`.`id_forum` DESC LIMIT 0 , 30'))
            {
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($id_forum, $title, $tekst, $dato, $id_brugere);
            $count_res = $stmt->num_rows;

            if($count_res > 0)
            {
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {    
            ?>
            <tr class="forumtoppen">
            <td class="titleforum"><?php echo $title;?> - <a href="">L&#230;se mere</a></td>
            <td>Dato: <?php echo $dato;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
                }
            else
                {
                ?>
                    <p>der er ingen overhovedet!.. hmm</p>
                <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

here where I've built it up like this there must be convert to Danish time.

```
<?php echo $dato;?>
```

there will be no errors but I just have to build it into Danish date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you use mysql's date_format function in the retrieve query? ([php docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format))

```
SELECT id_forum, title, tekst, date_format(dato,'%d-%m-%Y') as dato, id_brugere 
FROM `forum` 
ORDER BY  `forum` . `id_forum` DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I'll just copying what you've written?

Comment: try the query and see if it does what you want. only change from yours is date_format(dato,'%d-%m-%Y') as dato instead of dato.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/232/assst.png/

Here's how it looks after I try copying it over

Comment: no, the spaces are wrong. it should be `'%d-%m-%Y'`, no spaces. and you also should add the ` as dato ` so that you can get the value by name...

Comment: it continues to do what I show on the link before, the show still together as before: (

Comment: sorry, i don't understand the problem. check this http://cl.ly/3k0f0A0N1Q0A1c1G1i1Q

Comment: you will be able to help me privately because I do not understand it completely, hmm